# Python: datetime.today().date() crashes in Django but runs in terminal

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have the following code in a Django app that keeps crashing:

```
from datetime import *    
date_today = datetime.today().date()
```

If I run the *exact* same code in the terminal, everything works and it prints `datetime.date(2016, 11, 10)`

The error I get when the code is run i Django:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'today'
```

**Question:** What can I do to make the code run in Django?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guarantee you are not running that exact code in Django. Almost certainly, you did `import datetime` rather than `from datetime import *`.

Confusingly, the datetime module contains a class which is also called `datetime`; it is the class which is imported by the `from ...` syntax, and which has the `today` method.

Doing `import datetime` imports the module, which does *not* have that method; instead you would need to do `datetime.datetime.today()`.

Comment: You were right. I had a few other import statements underneath the datetime import, they overwrote the import.